# R shiny reactive list of files

Tags: r, shiny

New to shiny, I want my app to display all files in a directory, and make the list update every time a file is added or removed. I see this is possible with `reactivePoll`, so I put this in my server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    has.new.files <- function() {
        length(list.files())
    }
    get.files <- function() {
        list.files()
    }
    output$files <- renderText(reactivePoll(10, session, checkFunc=has.new.files, valueFunc=get.files))    
}
```

However, I don't know how I can access the character vector containing my files within my ui. I also doubt that `renderText` in my server is the right choice. Here is my ui (non-reactive, just reads file list once):

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    ## How to access the files from server function ??
    selectInput("file", "Choose file", list.files())
)
```

Thus, I just don't know hot to access the data, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  has.new.files <- function() {
    unique(list.files())
  }
  get.files <- function() {
    list.files()
  }

  # store as a reactive instead of output
  my_files <- reactivePoll(10, session, checkFunc=has.new.files, valueFunc=get.files)

  # any time the reactive changes, update the selectInput
  observeEvent(my_files(),ignoreInit = T,ignoreNULL = T, {
    print(my_files())
    updateSelectInput(session, 'file',choices = my_files())
  })

}


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("file", "Choose file", list.files())
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

It updates the `selectInput` any time a file is added, deleted or renamed. If you only want it to change if a file is added, you can replace the `has.new.files` function back with your own. Hope this helps!

Comment: But what to put in the ui? In your example, it is still `list.files()`, so it is still not reactive..

Comment: The ui is fine as it is, you can copy and paste the code in RStudio and try it out. It is initialized with `list.files()` in the UI, so it has values when the app is started. However, it is updated by the server every time the files in the directory (the reactive) changes.

Comment: Maybe see [here](https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/4bc6e6fee0cb707e2755) for an additional example. As you can see, the ui is initialized as static, and updated from the server.