# render new image from disk in R markdown / Dashboard on user selection dropdown

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, flexdashboard, crosstalk

I have a folder full of charts, generated from a previous step. All of them are PNG files.
I want to be able to choose anyone using Flexdashboard and load it.
As no shiny or server service is needed I tried Crosstalk package

```
library(crosstalk)
library(magrittr)
library(png)
    
df <- list.files("plots/", full.names = TRUE) %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      magrittr::set_names("path") 
    
    shared_data <- SharedData$new(df,  key = ~path)
    
    p <- shared_data %>% readPNG(source = path)
    
    bscols( filter_select(id = "file_id", 
                         label = "CHOOSE", 
                         sharedData = shared_data, 
                         group = ~path), 
           p)
```

I am stuck on a very simple error i cannot solve as all paths are properly read from file:

```
Error in path.expand(source) : invalid 'path' argument
```

Tried to use knitr too:

```
   bscols(filter_select("path", "CHOOSE", shared_data),
      knitr::include_graphics(shared_data, ~path))

Error in makeGroupOptions(sharedData, group, allLevels) : argument "group" is missing, with no default
```

Maybe there is a simpler approach but crosstalk seemed a very simple one as it does not need shiny or any other component but a data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated Answer (Oct 2023) -

##### Reactively adding new files to dropdown

AFAIK, If we want the UI to update itself every time new files are added, we will have to use Shiny and its reactive capabilities.
The server observes the directory for any new files and asynchronously updates the client's Selectinput every time a new file is added

```
library(shiny)

########################### Client ################################### 

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Image Viewer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("imgSelect", "Select an image", choices = NULL ),
      br(),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("imgDisplay")
    ) #mp
  )
)


########################### Server ################################### 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  image_dir <-  "plots"
  
  oldFiles<- function(){
    return(  list.files(path=image_dir, pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = TRUE))
  }
  nowFiles <- function() {
    return(list.files(path=image_dir, pattern = "\\.png$", full.names = TRUE))
  }
  
  # Constantly poll and check(compare) nowFiles against oldFiles
  imgData <- reactivePoll(3000, session, checkFunc = oldFiles , 
                          valueFunc = nowFiles)
  
  # Update dropdown  if files change
  observe({
    # Retain previous selection when new items are added 
    curr<- input$imgSelect #gives current selection
    if(curr ==''){ curr= imgData()[1] }
    # update ui
    updateSelectInput(session, "imgSelect", choices = imgData() , selected = curr )
  })
  
  #  Render new image on selection change
  observeEvent(input$imgSelect, {
    currImg <- input$imgSelect
   #image rendering
    output$imgDisplay <- renderImage({
      # return list to render image
      list(
        src = currImg,contentType = 'image/png',
        alt = "currImg"
      )
    }, deleteFile = FALSE) 
    #end image rendering
    
  })# End observeEvent
  
}#server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

#### Tip:

If you place the following lines **outside** the `server()` function, you can share the same file list across multiple sessions

```
image_dir <-  "plots"
imgData <- reactivePoll(3000, session = NULL, 
                        checkFunc = function() {list.files(path=image_dir,
                                                           pattern = "\\.png$",
                                                           full.names = TRUE)}  , 
                        valueFunc = function() {list.files(path=image_dir, 
                                                           pattern = "\\.png$", 
                                                           full.names = TRUE) })
```

---

#### Old/Accepted Answer (Oct 2021)

If all you need is a static setup , this still works, and accomplishes it with minimum fuss

````
```{r}
# 
library(stringr)
library(bsselectR)

state_plots <- paste0(list.files("plots", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))
names(state_plots) <- str_replace_all(state_plots, 
                                      c("\\.png" = "", 
                                        "plots/" = ""))


bsselect(state_plots, type = "img", selected = "sns_heatmap", 
         live_search = TRUE, show_tick = TRUE)


```
````

Output :

[image]

Comment: This fails when selecting other than the preselected picture. It only worked on load.

Comment: Let me check (tomorrow). I remember trying all the images in the dynamic drop down list.

Comment: I have the same problem. Only the pre-selected image shows on load. It seems the package is abandoned. Anyone know of an alternative?

Comment: @BillyRyan Yes I've realized that BSSelectR had this problem , but at that time I was not able to give it more time . However, Shiny server does have `reactive` capabilities , so it should certainly be possible to create a real-time list of files . Take a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48225100/5132823  From there ,  some sort of melding together of  these two codes should produce the desired result

Comment: @BillyRyan : Take a look at the new code I have added above. My R version is rather ancient , so I'd appreciate the feedback

Comment: @R.S. thank you for your code! I have considered a shiny solution, however that requires active hosting-my goal is to serve these static line with GitHub Pages.

Comment: @OK. Though I think github pages are out and out static.  BTW If you only want to create a demo , you can use the free service at https://www.shinyapps.io/ The free tier offers 25 active hours a month, but it might be more than enough. I have  one  app running there that I use almost daily for 15-20 minutes.